# Prove that $f_y$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ for $\frac{1}{2} < k \leq \frac{3}{2}$, but continuous for $k > 3$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $k>\frac{1}{2}$ and $f$ is a function in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Prove that $f_y$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ for $\frac{1}{2} < k \leq \frac{3}{2}$, but continuous for $k > 3$.

$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
(x^2 + y^2)^k\sin\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$}  \\
\end{cases}$

If possible, determine whether $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$. If exists, find $Df(0, 0)$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Btw, there is no $c$ in the definition of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @MartinR edited.

Comment: @MathAvengers, there is still no $c$ in the definition of $f$. (There is a $k$. Is that the parameter you're asking about?)

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes! sorry i have been looking at this question for so long, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $(x,y)\to x^2+y^2$ is smooth so you need only understand, $f(r)=r^k\sin(\frac{1}{r})$. Also, note, $r\sin(\frac{1}{r})\to 0$ as $ r\to 0$

A composition of differentiable functions is differentiable. We need only compute the derivative of f at zero as it is clearly differentiable elsewhere. $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^k\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{k-1}sin(\frac{1}{h})$. This limit now only depends on the value of k. If $k>1$ then the derivative exists and is zero. Otherwise it doesn't exist. Now compute the derivative elsewhere and see for which values of k you get continuity of $f_y$.

Comment: Do you mind explain a bit more? i still don't understand...

Comment: thanks for the edit, the only question i have is why set k > 1 ?